# Unable to compile class for JSP with Tomcat 8.5,Java 8 and Eclipse Photon 4.8.0

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat8.5

I am using Java 8, Tomcat 8.5 and Eclipse Photon 4.8.0

When I run tomcat server and hit JSP page it gives following error:

> SEVERE: Compilation error org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/SpringMVC] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred in the generated java file: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. with root cause org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

I have tried changing compilance to 1.7 in Java but issue still exists.

Could you please help ?

Comment: Can you please paste the error text as part of the question?

Comment: Is Java 8 being used to run both Eclipse and Tomcat, or is Tomcat using a newer version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compilation error: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157747/compilation-error-org-eclipse-jdt-internal-compiler-classfmt-classformatexcepti)

Comment: @nitind, I have set JAVA_HOME and env. PATH variable to java 8 only, eclipse is showing java 8 but when I hit java -version from command prompt, it shows me java 1.7, why is this happening ? Is this the reason for above JSP class not found error ?

Comment: The variables are irrelevant when you are launching from Eclipse. Which version is the server configured with in the Eclipse UI?

Comment: I tried with Tomcat 7 and 8.5